# how to combine where and order for SQL query

Tags: mysql, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have projects and grants that are connected through a match.  The grant has an expiration date.  I want to sort the matches of a project by the grants expiration date.

This get's me the matches based on expiration date:

```
def self.expires_date_between(from, to)
  Match.where(:grant_id => Grant.where("expires_at  >= ? and expires_at <= ?", from, to))
end
```

And this shows the matches based on a specific date range.

```
def current_matches
  range = user.current_period_range
  matches.expires_date_between(range[0], range[1])
end
```

This works great to show the grants based on a specific time period but the grants aren't showing in order of date (expires_at).  It appears that grants are being sorted by the date they were created instead. How can I change my query so that the grants are listed in order of expiration date?

I tried:

```
def self.expires_date_between(from, to)
  Match.where(:grant_id => Grant.where("expires_at  >= ? and expires_at <= ?", from, to).order('expires_at asc'))
end
```

This doesn't throw an error but it also doesn't change the order of the grants.  Any ideas?

Comment: Don't forget the `BETWEEN` operator which you can use with `where(expires_at: from .. to)`.

Comment: thanks for the tip, that makes my code much cleaner!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have defined your associations in your models, this should work (but has not been tested):

```
Match
  .joins(:grant)
  .merge(Grant.where("expires_at  >= ? and expires_at <= ?", from, to))
  .order('expires_at asc')
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I also added the suggestion from @tadman and ended up with `Match.joins(:grant).merge(Grant.where("expires_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", from, to)).order('expires_at asc')`.